# Dual-boot problems, installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2

Hello here is my system, Currently running on windows 8.1

[image]

[image]

Created new partition -> installed ubuntu on there (When installing the Ubuntu, I cannot see any options that has "... install along Windows 8". I can only see option to erase the disk which is I dont want), and done. After computer restarts, my pc does not detect Ubuntu, and it proceed to windows 8.1. So I use EasyBCD, and I added the Ubuntu there

[image]

[image]

Anyone can help me if I missed something??
Thanks!

Comment: take a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported it's not that simple to install Ubuntu on GPT-disk alongside Win8

Comment: you can find a lot of questions and answers about installing Ubuntu alongside Windows within this forum

Comment: Thank you, I've read the guide on that post. Unfortunately I'm stuck here, my powershell output was "Cmdlet not supported on this platform", which according to his post, I can install Ubuntu by simply inserting the LiveCD or LiveUSB and doing the installation procedure without any problems. Though it's not, I'm stuck on the grub console after installation!

Comment: did you read it to the end? and did everything as follows? you installed `boot-repair` updated `grub` and disabled `secure boot` after all?

Comment: Thank you, boot-repair fixed the issue and grub is now showing properly but after that my windows 8 doesnt appear there.

so I have to run os-probe, update grub, and finally got win 8 works alongside with ubuntu!

Comment: you're welcome, good for you.

Answer (score 0):

Did the Ubuntu entry you added in EasyBCD show up when you restart Windows?

If no, go to `run > msconfig > second tab (Boot) > increase timeout` and restart.

If yes, did it work? If it showed up but didn't work, try editing the Ubunty entry in EasyBCD by specifying the drive for your `boot` (or `root`?) partition.

[image]

Comment: Yeah the entry appears after I rebooted my pc, I created two entries for my ubuntu, one is using "Automatically Locate and Load" and other one is the location of my "/boot", not sure why but both of them have same output (stuck on GRUB> black console screen)